# Checkbox color change android

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox and i want to change its color. I am attaching a pic for more understanding. [image]

I want to change the black squares color to white just like the text "Press to skip". My xml code is below:

```
<CheckBox
 android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
 android:background="@drawable/tutorial_screen_edit_text_style"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
 android:text="Press to Skip"
 android:textColor="@color/white"

 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is very simple, check this code snippet below:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
android:background="@drawable/tutorial_screen_edit_text_style"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
android:text="Press to Skip"
android:buttonTint="@color/white"    <!--just add this line-->
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro, you are the best and saved me alot of time :)

Comment: Always happy to help brother :)

Answer (score 3):

try using ColorStateList

```
    ColorStateList  colorStateList = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked} , // checked
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.parseColor("#000000"),  //unchecked color
                Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"),  //checked color
        }
);
```

set the color using: `setButtonTintList()`

```
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
 CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(cb,colorStateList);
```

Comment: Does this also applies for minSdk 21 to 30?

Comment: @mochadwi yes.. the minimum sdk for setButtonTIntList() is 21.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton#setButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! No need to use `compoundDrawableTintList` anymore in my parts. Previously still using `compoundDrawableTintList` but somehow it not works if modified at runtime using `compoundDrawableTintList`

Comment: In the other hands. `setButtonTintList` works seamlessly on runtime, e.g: `button.setOnClickListener { checkbox.setButtonTintList(..., ...) }`

Answer (score 0):

define your own drawalbe in drawalbe folder

checkbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox" 
          android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxselected" 
          android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox"/>    
</selector>
```

your_layout.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" />
```

Comment: i didnt understand the drawables part, what do they do?

Comment: you need to find white square images for every state of checkBox you generate them with this [link](https://android-material-icon-generator.bitdroid.de/#section-material-icons)

Comment: you can use the following for checkbox and checkboxselected drawable, http://www.clker.com/cliparts/B/2/v/i/n/T/tick-check-box-md.png and http://www.clker.com/cliparts/e/q/p/N/s/G/checkbox-unchecked-md.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
     <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chk_remember_signup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:buttonTint="@android:color/white"
                        android:text="hello" />
```